# How do these approaches to death in Wednesday go together?

Tags: addams-family, wednesday

The question is about 2022 Netflix series **Wednesday**.

On one side all members of the Addams seems to enjoy everything connected with suffering and death.
Wednesday herself actually almost kills someone in the very first scene (on purpose).

On the other hand, the possibility that

> Gomez killed someone

seems to be dramatic and certainly not *cool*. It is perceived as an issue and unforgivable wrongdoing (even by Wednesday).

How does it go together?

Comment: Since I don't have an in-universe answer (actually, I haven't watched the series at all), I'm going to put this in a comment: it's a culture thing. The Addamses are obsessed with the macabre, to the point that it's normal for them. However, they are still moral people; Gomez is big into family honor, Wednesday feels horror (and not the good kind) at the possibility that her father may have done something bad, etc.

Comment: (cont.) To give a real-world example from my own experience as an assisted living employee: we talk about disease, death, and everything that goes with it frivolously. It's no big deal to us. We'd talk joke about it, talk about it during meals, etc. A lot of the beside manner training aides and nurses have to do is to get them to remember that not everybody shares their nuanced view on matters. The thing is, while we have no problem with death (people who do tend to quit after walking in on a corpse for the first time), we take umbrage at things like abuse and murder.

Comment: Fair to say, they have a grave-yard in the garden (family, pets and who knows what else), it's everyday life for them.

Comment: Wednesday was also offended at the secret as much as the crime.  If humor is based on suffering - Attempted murder is comedy.  Also it may be cartoon logic but even in previous live versions (like baby Pubert in AF2) the Addams seem a bit indestructible - so killing normal folks just may not be fair cricket.  Example in 90s cartoon https://youtu.be/JHprsqR84Vc also while it is safe to say the audience considers Wednesday consistent with the homicidal 90s movies.  We haven't seen the main Addams at home. They may be more kooky than 90s versions.

Answer (score 2):

**Wednesday is offended by lies and secrets**

Wednesday would have been proud had her father murdered someone, but she knows too much to be pleased by the idea that he had. Why?

1. She knows that "he doesn't have it in him." The idea that he murdered someone is a falshood due to his inability to commit such a crime, implying a secret that she doesn't know. That everyone is keeping the secret from her irritates her to no end.
2. When her father, in jail, explains the modified story that keeps the burden of guilt on him, *she almost believes it.* And would have been perfectly satisfied with his being a murderer — except that she *knows his tells,* and therefore knows he's lied to her — and that offends her, too.

After watching the series several times (my wife loves it, I'm fond of it myself), I don't believe there's any difference in the "approach to death" that is the macabre world built by author Charles Addams.

I think Wednesday is being completely consistent. She's the ultimate 16-going-on-30 teenager who knows enough to know that the world isn't working the way it should, but not enough to know there are reasons adults do the silly things they do.

Like lie to children.